# Doctrine issues when using JOIN and WHERE

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I have a simple doctrine code:

```
$dql = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('u.ident, u.username, u.email')
        ->from('Users u, u.Attributes ua');
if ($query) {
  $dql->where('u.username LIKE ?', "%$query%")
    ->orWhere('u.name LIKE ?', "%$query%")
    ->orWhere('u.email LIKE ?', "%$query%");
}
$dql->offset($start)->limit($count);
$users = $dql->execute();
```

With the profiler, I found out that Doctrine is running this as two separate queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e3.ident FROM users e3 
LEFT JOIN userpolicies e4 ON e3.ident = e4.user_id 
WHERE e3.username LIKE ? OR e3.name LIKE ? OR e3.email LIKE ? LIMIT 20

Params:
Array
(
    [0] => %fam%
    [1] => %fam%
    [2] => %fam%
)
```

and

```
SELECT e.ident AS e__ident, e.username AS e__username, e.email AS e__email FROM users e
LEFT JOIN userpolicies e2 ON e.ident = e2.user_id 
WHERE e.ident IN ('2', '40', '42', '44', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '58', '60', '61', '62', '64', '65', '66', '68', '70', '74', '82') AND e.username LIKE ? OR e.name LIKE ? OR e.email LIKE ?

Params:
Array
(
    [0] => %fam%
    [1] => %fam%
    [2] => %fam%
)
```

This is not exactly what I have in mind because the second query applies the WHERE conditions a second time even after the matching rows from 'Users' are selected in the first query (i.e., the second query should stop with `WHERE e.ident IN ()`). Is this my screw-up or the expected behaviour of Doctrine? I'm using doctrine v1.1.6.

Answer (score 2):

Well, looks like this issue was fixed in Doctrine version 1.2. Switching to it now :) Sorry for the trouble, guys.